# Thread is not seeing refreshed value with lock

Tags: c++, multithreading

How do you force a thread to see the updated value of a shared variable? I thought mutexes were supposed to help, but in the code below, I don't see the correct behavior:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

mutex coutm;

class Timer {
    public:
        Timer() : 
            m_start(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()),
            m_elapsedTime (0) {}
        ~Timer() {};
        void start() {
            while (m_elapsedTime < 50) {
                unique_lock<mutex> timerLock{m_timerMutex};
                m_elapsedTime += chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - m_start).count();
                unique_lock<mutex> lck{coutm};
                cout << "Timer thread. New timer value = " << m_elapsedTime << endl; 
                this_thread::yield();
            }
            unique_lock<mutex> lck{coutm};
            cout << "Time = " << m_elapsedTime << ". Done!" << endl;
        }
        double getElapsedTime() { 
            return m_elapsedTime;
        }
    private:
        double m_elapsedTime;
        decltype(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()) m_start;
    public:
        mutex m_timerMutex;
};

void dummyPrint(Timer& m) {
    unique_lock<mutex> timerLock{m.m_timerMutex};
    auto t = m.getElapsedTime();
    while (t < 50) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck{coutm};
        cout << "Waiting... Time = " << t << endl;
        this_thread::yield();
    }
}

int main() {
    Timer t;
    thread timerThread {&Timer::start, std::ref(t)};
    thread t1{&dummyPrint, std::ref(t)};
    timerThread.join();
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

My dummyPrint() function always sees a 0 value for the time even though access to Timer::m_elapsedTimer is guarded by a mutex. I'm sure I'm using mutexes wrong, but I don't understand what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Did you mean to refresh the value of `t` inside the loop?

Comment: Stupid me! Yes. That was supposed to be inside the loop! Thanks.

Comment: `Timer::start` isn't protecting its access to `m_elapsedTime` in the loop condition or the final print, either, and `dummyPrint` doesn't release the lock until the end of the function.

Comment: You could use `std::atomic<double> m_elapsedTime;` to prevent UB

Comment: Changed it like so: http://cpp.sh/83x2c

Comment: dummyPrint never releases the mutex, so start can never acquire the mutex.

Comment: @curiouscoder: You should edit the question if you're still having problems after your modifications. Also, you should probably note that you're calling `yield` while still holding the lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
thread timerThread {&Timer::start, std::ref(t)};
thread t1{&dummyPrint, std::ref(t)};
```

Just because you constructed the `timerThread` first, and `t1` after it, you have no guarantees whatsoever that `Timer::start` will run first, in its execution thread, and `dummyPrint` will run second, in its own execution thread. And not only that it has to start executing first, it also has to lock the mutex first, in order for you to see your expected results. That's not guaranteed either. Your only guarantee here is that the new execution thread will enter the thread function at some point after `std::thread` is fully constructed. That's it.

For whatever reason, on your particular C++ implementation, the `dummyPrint` execution thread manages to get its act together first, locks the mutex, and finds that it hasn't been initialized, and `m_elapsedTime` is still 0. This is the behavior you are seeing.

You have very few guarantees, when it comes to multiple execution threads. If you require specific behavior you will need to enforce it yourself. Here, the simplest course of action is to add a separate `bool` flag, and a condition variable that indicates that `timerThread` finished initialization. `timerThread` initializes everything, sets the flag, and signals the condition variable. `main` waits for the flag to be set, before constructing the second `std::thread`.

P.S. Don't skimp on condition variables. `yield` is not as reliable as properly using condition variables.